# Excel | Populate multiple cells based on If condition

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a sheet full of staff names with their breaks (every staff has 3 breaks) and on the other side I have intervals list for the time written horizontally in 1 row [00:00,00:05,00:10...etc Untill you reach 23:55] 
I want excel to populate the interval cells based on the break duration.
So, If John Doe is on break from 00:05 to 00:20. I want to populate the intervals from 00:05 to 00:20 with number 1, and If another staff's break is falling within the same duration, that will add another 1 to make it 2.

my table structure as follows:

```
  Emp ID  |  Emp Name  | Break Start | Break End | Duration (15 min or 20 min)             00:00|00:05|00:10|00:15|00:20|00:25  ....etc
    123   |  John Doe  |    00:05    |   00:20   |  00:15                                          1      1     1
    456   |  Richard   |    00:10    |   00:25   |  00:15                                                 1     1     1
```

What I already have as Formula, Is `=IF(The break start cell = The Interval Cell,1,0)` , But It only populates the interval cell which equals the break start, Ignoring the other adjacent cells that needs to be populated also according to the break duration. like we did above in the structure.

Thanks Guys! :)

Comment: So it is not very clear what you are trying to accomplished. But why dont you just add the cell above it? `=IF(The break start cell = The Interval Cell,1,0) + Adjacent Cell`

Comment: That would give him 1's all the from the break start to the end. @AlyAbdelaziz

Comment: Maybe i have not understood or miscommunicated it. But the Adjacent cell is the data the OP **populated on the right**. So basically he would be adding the value '1' and is the data has become '2' he would be adding one to that. @JacobEdmond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
=IF(AND(The Interval Cell >= The break start cell , The break start cell + Duration Cell > The Interval Cell),1,0)
```

Comment: Buddy, you don't know how much of work you've saved me with this line of formula ! :)) 
working perfectly as I wanted.
Thanks a ton!